# Yahoo Finance charts as image file

Tags: charts, yahoo-finance

A while ago Yahoo Finance changed its API and since then the download of `.csv` data hasn't been working anymore via the old method. This already has been discussed in several other questions.

However, the old version also allowed to download charts of a certain symbol via `https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=<<TICKER>>` in form of a `.png` file which now also doesn't work anymore. The new chart viewer only seems to display data through painting on a canvas from a JS script, and there doesn't seem to be a "download as image" feature either.

So is there any way on the new website to get charts for a ticker symbol in form of a `.png` or `.svg` file through a GET/POST request, if possible with the option to define parameters as in the the old version?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same, not sure what happened to the old way to get stock images. If I find something out I'll post it here, if you could pls let me know as well if you do?

Comment: Sure, I will post any new insights here

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using  [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/). There is a blogpost here: [How To Capture Element Screenshot Using Selenium WebDriver](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/01/how-to-capture-element-screenshot-using.html). Selenium has binding to several languages including Java and Python. Very powerful for testing webpages, but can be used to scrape information from sites with complex footprint and not very user friendly implementation.

Comment: Since Selenium is often a lot of work to setup and maintain, there are also dedicated static chart API like [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com)

Comment: Just he asks for stock charts (stock market stocks) and not a way to construct a chart from own data since he also does not have the data.